Identifying variables outside of function calls
I want to identify variables outside of function calls such as
result = someFunction(arg1, arg2) + 10

And I used pattern ([a-zA-Z_]\w*)(?!\s*\()
In Matlab, the result is
{'result'}    {'someFunctio'}    {'arg1'}    {'arg2'}

But, I want to get
{'result'}    {'arg1'}    {'arg2'}

I'm curious why the function call is also extracted.
And also why it is someFunctio.

Because you did not specify the word boundary, '([a-zA-Z_]\w*)\>(?!\s*\()'. The \> is the boundary for the end of the word.

Actually, boundary does not work in Matlab as I know...

I edited the comment. The word boundaries just look different there.

Note that variable names starting with an underscore are not valid, but this looks like it allows them.

your question is not clear. please explain little more

If you are just after extracting words at the start of a line before a =, use ^\s*([a-zA-Z_]\w*)\s*=

([a-zA-Z]\w*)\>(?!\s*\() This one works
Sorry for unclear question....
The purpose was extract all variable names including left-hand side of equal

Adding word boundaries fixes it: (\b[a-zA-Z_]\w*\b)(?!\s*\()
